# Parallelize Scala's Iterator

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, iterator, scala-collections

**Please note:** This is not a duplicate question, since this question specifies on all methods `Iterator` has, not just `map` and `flatMap`. Therefore `Future.traverse` are not a good answer.

Let's say I have this simple statement:

```
(1 to 100).toSet.subsets.find(f)
```

It works perfectly. It's lazy, doesn't use a lot of memory and returns as soon as one element is found. The problem starts when you want to parallelize it. You might say, it's Scala, there has to be `.par` or `Iterator`, but there isn't.

The proposed solution on the internet is to use `.grouped`, but it's not as good as I'd want. Why?

```
val it = (1 to 100).toSet.subsets.grouped(1000000).map(_.par.find(f)).flatten
if (it.hasNext) Some(it.next) else None
```

1. Uses much more memory. I know it's still O(1), but let's be perfect here :)
2. It's not perfectly parallelizable (by Amdahl's law). When `.grouped` is consuming the iterator for next block of million elements, all but one thread waits. This is especially problematic if iterator is expensive to consume. Moreover, there has to be an overhead of spawning a new set of threads to work on a new block.
3. Produces more complicated / longer code (see example). It would shorten code a bit if `Iterator` had `.nextOption`, but still.

Is there anything else despite programming my own producer-consumer model (iterator is producer, threads are consumers) and then final reduce step?

Comment: There is no way to parallelize Iterator in general: as a counter example consider Iterator over infinite sequence of fibonacci numbers.

Comment: There isn't anything built-in, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17178201/1180426)

Comment: @om-nom-nom: I don't agree. If code terminates with non-parallel iterator, it'll terminate with paralell iterator, too. What do i mean? If you run `.sum` on you example, both will run infinitely, however, `.find` will return in both cases if an element exists.

Comment: And I don't agree with you :-) Isn't having operation that terminates iff we lucky enough to have such element in sequence kinda ... corner case, that contradicts with *in general* statement? Nevertheless, your options are either parallelizing processing of batch of elements produced (**sequentially**) by the iterator OR if you know that it fits memory materializing it to some collection (**sequentially**) which *is* parallelizable.

Comment: Isn't `Iterator` consuming the values it points to such that we can iterate only once over collection? How would you like to iterate then? First `iterator` consumes i.e elements from 1 to 1000, second from 2000 to 3000 etc?

Comment: @goral: It would probably be the most efficient option to take them in blocks, like you suggested. It would however have to be dynamical, since you don't know how costly is the function going to be. I guess 1, 2, 4, 8 would work.

Comment: You can make use of `sliding` method from `Set` library. Then pass each `Set` to different instanties of your merge-sort algorithm. Then when all parts are finished merge them.

Comment: @goral, that is not true. If you want to process subsets of a set, you cannot partition the problem like that. For example, you'd get more than one empty set, from each "slide" you get one. You agree?

Comment: Why would it result in empty set?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178201/parallel-iterator-in-scala. But the question here gives an answer that's not given for the old question: the groupBy

Comment: @goral: I didn't say that. I have said you are going to process the same sets multiple times. Take a look: `Set(1,2,3).sliding(2).flatMap(_.subsets).toList`
gives the result
`res2: List(Set(), Set(1), Set(2), Set(1, 2), Set(), Set(2), Set(3), Set(2, 3))` (notice empty set appearing twice, therefore you'd have its result twice in the final, merged set)

Comment: `val setIterator = Set(1,2,3,4,5,6).sliding(2,2)
setIterator.foreach(println)` yields `Set(5,1) Set(6,2) Set(3,1)` order here is random of course.

Comment: The problem is that you need to know number of elements beforehand to properly set parameters of the `sliding` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.toStream`. This will produce a lazy stream that will memoize values. And it has `.par` on it.

It will allocate some wrappers on the heap but if you're careful(not hold around pointers to the stream) this will only result in GC pressure but not in increasing residual memory footprint. It will still go quite fast. Please mind that parallel collections induce quite a lot of overhead and might not be worth it if your per-element computation is not expensive enough.

Iterators are just too low-level to parallelize. But you don't actually need a parallel iterator but rather a parallel traversal of the iterator you can have [Future.traverse](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future%24) from the standard library.

Comment: The problem with this solution is: `.par` on Stream returns ordinary `ParSeq`, that means a whole stream is consumed before it is evaluated in parallel.