# any more efficient methods to get the columns different from each other?

Tags: scala

a txt file (1.txt) and column delimiter is a space for each row

content as following(in fact,there are many lines...):

```
1 2 3 4
a b c d
1 1 1 1
1 1 2 2
```

expected:

```
1 2 3 4
a b c d
```

now, i can get the correct output by as following code:

```
val lines = io.Source.fromFile("/root/1.txt").getLines
lines.filterNot(_.split("\\s+").distinct.length<4).foreach(println)
```

but, any more efficient methods to realize it ?

for example: multithreading or akka to realize it, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to process the file concurrently one option would be to use parallel collections. so a file with large number of records will be processed parallel with multiple threads.

**Note**: make sure the heap space is sized accordingly to support a very large file. One could also use parallel iterators provided by a third party library as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30793360/647129)

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/root/1.txt").getLines.toSeq.par
lines.filterNot(_.split("\\s+").distinct.length<4).foreach(println)
```

Comment: `file with large number of records` `toSeq` maybe will cause **OOM** issue.